# CLUSTER BY usage with Spark SQL queries

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I recently got introduced to Spark-SQL. I read somewhere about using `CLUSTER BY` on `join` columns (before the join) to improve `join` performance. Example:

```
create temporary view prod as
select id, name
from product
cluster by id; 

create temporary view cust as
select cid, pid, cname
from customer
cluster by pid;

select c.id, p.name, c.name 
from prod p
join cust c
on p.id = c.pid;
```

Can anyone please explain In which scenarios the same should be leveraged ? I understand that for join, data is shuffled. Then what benefits does `CLUSTER BY` brings in, since it also shuffles the data ?

Thanks.

Comment: please refer this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dv7IIYuQOXI

Comment: Actually a good question, sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the SQL interface you can do things without having to use the DF interface.

`Cluster By` is the same as:

```
df.repartition($"key", n).sortWithinPartitions()
```

Due to lazy evaluation, Spark will see the JOIN and know that you indicate  you want a repartition by key - via SQL, not like statement directly above - so it is just the interface amounting to the same thing. Makes it easier to stay in SQL mode only. You can intermix.

If you do not do it, then Spark will do it for you (in general) and apply the current shuffle partitions parameter.

```
SET spark.sql.shuffle.partitions = 2
SELECT * FROM df CLUSTER BY key
```

is the same as:

```
df.repartition($"key", 2).sortWithinPartitions()
spark.sql('''SELECT /*+ REPARTITION(col,..) */ cols... from table''')
```

UPDATE

This does not apply to a JOIN in this way:

```
val df = spark.sql(""" SELECT /*+ REPARTITION(30, c1) */ T1.c1, T1.c2, T2.c3
                         FROM T1, T2   
                        WHERE T1.c1 = T2.c1
                   """)
```

What this does is to repartition *after* processing the JOIN. The JOIN will use the higher of partitioning nums set on T1 and T2, or shuffle partitions if not set explicitly.

Comment: How does `Cluster By` (before a Join) improve join performance ? What is the benefit of using `Cluster By` in a sql and what situations should we use it ?

Comment: Again, just like the other question you had, just alternative syntax. If you do not specify like this then, then Spark will do it for you using default shuffle partition size, but here you can do it in %sql mode. There's not much in it, they to cater for those wanting to stay SQLish in approach, but you need to set that first parameter.

Comment: since you mentioned `repartition()` in the `DF` interface, could you also let me know what will the equivalent syntax in the `SQL` interface ?

Comment: added to the question

Comment: thanks much.. your example indicates the hint syntax to specify the partition column, however, for join queries, which involve more than 1 table, is it possible to specify the intended table name, column name and the no. of partitions all together in a single hint ?

Comment: add to answer - more complicated than you may realize

Comment: thanks again, in that case instead of using a hint, i can `repartition` the table in one query by using `cluster by` (like you advised above) and then do the `join` in a different subsequent query. Will that work ?

Comment: thanks again.. of course i will accept your answer. Btw,just to be sure that I understood correctly - we can use `cluster by` to repartition a table (eg Table-1), **prior** to the actual `Join` with another table (eg Table-2), which happens in a subsequent query.. correct ?

Comment: On the update I address that aspect. When u join, Spark must have similar to join data on same Worker. If clustering partitioning not done then Spark will do it for you. If you do it yourself you can cluster both tables manually  but Spark will look and see if it makes sense. Sparks default is 200. You can influence by setting the shuffle params. I have to say it is the sql approach but it is for all intents and purposes a little confusingly presented. Hope this helps.

Comment: so based on your previous comment regarding using `cluster by` on a table and then performing the `join`, is there a way to also specify the `num partitions` as well with `cluster by` ?  in that case, if the `num-partitions` differ on both the input branches (of the join) will `spark` add `exchanges` on both branches to level out the num-partitions on both sides ? In that case, it will hit the performance, correct? Of course, i could use the hint (as you advised) to specify the num-partitions, but just trying to understand its possibility

Comment: In the UPD: it takes the appropriate setting. If you have T1 and T2 with 2 different # of partitions it will take the higher value for BOTH, else it will look at the current default setting and apply to both / more tables in the JOIN.

Comment: i tried out the REPARTITION hint as you had advised earlier but it is throwing an error : `REPARTITION hint expects a partition number as parameter`. I used `/*+ REPARTITION(500, c1) */`. Any suggestions ? I am using `Spark 2.4`

Comment: version 3 is needed for this.

Comment: then i should use `cluster by` like explained above. Will give the same results ?

Comment: Yes, functionally you will always get the same results.

Answer (score 1):

Spark will recognize the cluster by and shuffle the data. However, if you use the same columns in later queries that induce shuffles, Spark might re-use the exchange.